# Ensure string value from JSON response

Tags: objective-c, types, casting

I have a webservice spitting out JSON responses from the database, which I intend to use in my iPad app.

However, depending on the server where the webservice is run, it either casts integers to integers or returns them as string. As I cannot be sure of the type, I have to take care of either way in my app.

So, I have a NSDictionary from which I obtain the value using `objectForKey:`. I then tried calling `stringValue` but apparently that only works if the value is not a string already.

Is there a simple method for enforcing a string type when having either a NSString or a NSInteger instance?

Comment: If your JSON contains an integer value, isn't that wrapped into an `NSNumber` in order to be stored in an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`? Cannot prove it right now, but if so you could do `NSString *definitelyAString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", unsureString]; (your unsureString is the value you get through `objectForKey:`

Comment: Perfect! Submit this as an answer and you'll get the points. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
NSString *definitelyAString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", unsureString];
```

where `unsureString` is the value you get through `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringValue;
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
   stringValue = value;
}
else
{  
   stringValue = [value stringValue];
}
```

Comment: stringValue = [value isKindForClass:[NSString class]]?value:[value stringValue];

For those, who believe that length is a question of letters.

Comment: Not that there would be such a thing as short in Objective-C. ;)